# Implementing fuction that takes in array and multiplies each element by given int

Tags: python, arrays, int

```
def multAll(A, k):
    # takes an array of integers and an int, and multiplies each integer by the int.
    for i in A:
        i = i*k
        return i

# test 1

A = [5,12,31,7,25]
multAll(A, 10)
print(A)  # should print [50,120,310,70,250]
```

What am I doing wrong in multAll that isnt giving me the correct answer?

Comment: Is the return inside the loop in the actual code? That should likely be after, outside the loop.

Comment: To reiterate what @Carcigenicate said, as soon as a function hits a `return` statement, the function stops...functioning and just returns what it was told. The way this is written, it will pull the first element of the list, mulltiply it, then return the value and exit the function

Answer (score 3):

When `return i` happens for the first time in your function, the function stops and returns the current `i`.

```
def multAll(A, k):
    return_value = []
    for i in A:
        i = i*k
        return_value.append(i)
    return return_value
```

Like this, a complete list `return_value` is created, and that list is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired result:

```
def multAll(A, k):
    return [i * k for i in A]
```

It is using the [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) pattern that allows you to edit each element of the list.

Comment: While this is a complete and very efficient answer, it doesn't really answer the OP question of "what am I doing wrong" in a way that might help them learn

Comment: This still seems to be returning the same elements - I mean, without it being multiplied by 10?

Comment: @navysoul No, zipa's function will return a new list whose elements have been multiplied. But please note the distinction between *returning a new list* and *modifying the old list*. You can test zipa's code by writing `print(multAll(A, 10))` or `B = multAll(A, 10); print(B)`. The original list `A` will not be modified. If you want to modify the old list rather than return a new list, then don't use the `return` keyword at all, and instead write `def multAll(A, k): for i in range(len(A)): A[i] = A[i] * k`.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your function should *not* return the given list; it should return the value of A[0] * k, the scalar 50.

Let's walk through the code for a moment, as you *should* have done with a `print` statement before posting.

```
for i in A:
    # i is a local variable; it takes on the value of A[0], or 5
    i = i*k
    # i is now 50
    return i
    # You return 50 to the calling program -- which ignores the return value.
```

At this point, the function is *done*, gone, exited, and will execute no more until you call it again.

To get the list (you have a **list**, *not* an **array*) altered, you can change each element in place.  Don't leave the function until you've processed *all* of the elements.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i] *= k

return
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the `multAll` function without expecting a returning value, you should update the list `A` in-place by updating its item values through indices:

```
def multAll(A, k):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        A[i] *= k
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are not the objects, so In loop every time you get only the next value of a list. And to that value, you do that operation. You should iterate over indexes, and assign a value to a specific place in the list. You could use the range function to do that.

Another problem is that you return value after calculating the first value in the list, so you should remove one indention.