# Multiply each element in a list recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to multiply each element of a list A in python by an int k recursively using no loops. My code so far is not correct as it does not modify the original array but creates a copy A. I realize that I have to define an auxiliary function `multAllRec(k,A,i)` to do this, and am wondering how I might go about doing this.

```
def multAll(k,A):
    if A == []: 
        return 
    A[0] = A[0]*k      
    return multAll(k, A[1:])

print(multAll(10, [5,12,31,7,25]))
```

Comment: You explicitely create a copy: `A[1:]`

Comment: is your intention to modify the input?

Comment: I am trying to modify the original array, hence the auxiliary function.

Comment: Is there a point to use recursion other than for the sake of it? This is a 1 level list and recursion will not implement it different than any list. The underlying implementation of `map` etc are also list bound. you can simply do `list(map(lambda x: x*10, A))` to achieve your functionality.

Comment: Sigh... so it was homework after all. Um, no use keeping it open.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modifying the Original

You're not too far off. You need to be careful about how you're returning from the recursive call.

When modifying the original, your recursive case will need to be a bit different. Just multiply the first element and update in-place. Pass the entire list in the recursive call. Also, have a function argument keep track of the current index to modify.

```
def multAll(A, i, k):
    if i < len(A):
        A[i] *= k
        multAll(A, i+1, k)
```

```
A = [5, 12, 31, 7, 25]
multAll(A, 0, 10)
print(A)
[50, 120, 310, 70, 250]
```

---

#### Returning a New List

```
def multAll(A, k):
   if not A: 
       return []         
   return [A[0] * k] + multAll(A[1:], k)

print(multAll([5, 12, 31, 7, 25], 10))
[50, 120, 310, 70, 250]
```

When returning from the recursive call, multiply the first element with `k`, listify it, and concatenate with the result of the recursive call that operates on `A[1:]` (also a list).

In the base case, return an empty list.

Comment: Lets say I wanted to return the answer in a new array called B, how would I do that?

Comment: @Frankt321 See second half of answer and do `B = multAll([5, 12, 31, 7, 25], 10)`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are creating a new array with `A[1:]`.

```
def multAll(k,A, curr):
    if curr == len(A):
        return
    A[curr] = A[curr]*k
    return multAll(k, A, curr + 1)

AA = [5,12,31,7,25]
multAll(10, AA, 0)
print(AA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.  When you return the result of the function, you forgot to append the current iteration's result to the front of the recursive result:

```
def multAll(k,A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return []
    return [A[0]*k] + multAll(k, A[1:])

print(multAll(10, [5,12,31,7,25]))
```

Output:

```
[50, 120, 310, 70, 250]
```

Comment: You already closed this question once before :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764298/implementing-fuction-that-takes-in-array-and-multiplies-each-element-by-given-in

Comment: LOL.  Same problem, different question.  The first one was specifically trying to modify the input list; this poster is (apparently) trying to return a new list.